# Escape XML special chars in AJAX

Tags: xml, ajax, escaping

I have an XML document which contains some invalid characters (é for example). Unfortunalty I cannot change the source XML file, and the file must be read through AJAX. How can I escape these characters client side?

Much thanks,

Steve

EDIT:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://foo.com",


        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('images').each(function(){
                $(this).find('pic').each(function() {
                    ...code...
                });

            });
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(textStatus);
        } 

    })
```

Comment: "é" is not an invalid character for XML and does not need escaping. Although depending on your case it might not be properly encoded.

Comment: its using utf-8, and that é is causing parse errors in IE, and Safari

Comment: What content type header does your server send? What is the actual encoding of the file on the server? Is there encoding="???" in the beginning of the XML file. These three must match if you want to avoid problems.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sovled this one my self by convincing the admins for properly format their XML files. Once they removed/fixed the special characters, the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

escape() and unescape() don't work for your architecture?

Comment: where would I add this in my posted example

Comment: nowhere, in your posted example. if the problem is during the jquery execution (parsing the results), then you really have to find out why it is failing (since é is totally valid in xml)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're looking for following xml processing instruction (PI):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

**EDIT 1**: client-side solution:

Can you read that xml content as string? If yes, replace existing PI by that above and .loadXML()

**EDIT 2**: Consider this link [Specifying the Data Type for AJAX Requests](http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests)